# h:message doesn't display JSF message

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In my JSF application, here's a simplified version of part of my form:

```
<h:form id="loginFormId">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputText value="Login :" />
        <h:inputText label="Login" id="loginId" />
        <rich:message for="loginId" ajaxRendered="true"/>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <a4j:commandButton value="OK" action="#{authentifierUtilisateurBean.authentifierUtilisateur}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </a4j:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

and here's a simplified version of my Managed Bean method authentifierUtilisateur() :

```
public String authentifierUtilisateur() {
    try {
        utilisateurEnBase = utilisateurDao.chercherParLogin( utilisateur.getLogin() );
    } 
    ...
    if ( utilisateurEnBase == .... ) {
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, bundle.getString("authentifier.utilisateur.login.inconnu"),"" );
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("loginFormId:loginId", message );
    }
```

I'd like to assign an error to the rich:message tag associated with the h:inputText based on something happening in the authentifierUtilisateur() method.
A validator is not possible, because the method that will deliver results from the DB is run in the authentifierUtilisateur() method.

When I try the above code, the page doesn't display message in front of the h:inputText.

If I insert in the form, the code

```
<rich:messages />
```

(messages with an s) above the button as follows:

```
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <rich:messages />
            <a4j:commandButton value="OK" action="#{authentifierUtilisateurBean.authentifierUtilisateur}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </a4j:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
```

then I can see the message so I am sure that the server sends correctly message to the client. 
So why the client doesn't display h:message in front of the h:inputText?
Is there something wrong in the Managed Bean?

```
addMessage("loginFormId:loginId", message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FacesMessage` consists of a summary and a detail, `rich:message` will display the detail by default. That's the one you're leaving empty so there's nothing to display. Either fill in the detail or set @showSummary="true"

Answer (score 0):

Insert an id to the h:panelGrid  i.e

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" id="grid">
```

Then in java code try this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("loginFormId:grid:loginId", message );
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you for help but this was not the reason of my error. Makhiel's answer pointed out my mistake.